# Variable With TOP Keyword Can't Be Used Together

Tags: sql, sybase, sap-ase

So in the query below, I am getting the error that there is incorrect syntax next to the keyword TOP and ORDER BY. I don't see a syntax issue with either. After further testing, it seems that my database platform doesn't allow TOP and ORDER BY in a derived table. Does anyone see a workaround for this query? I can't seem to find another way to have an integer variable after TOP. The unfortunate platform that I am using is SqlDbx.

```
DECLARE @SQL VARCHAR(16384)
DECLARE @CC_N INT

SELECT 
    @CC_N = B.PP - A.CC_PP 
FROM
(
    SELECT 
        Carline, 
        SUM(PP_Floor) AS CC_PP
    FROM PP_Balancing
    WHERE Carline = '01'
    GROUP BY Carline
) AS A
JOIN PP_National AS B ON A.Carline = B.Carline

SET @SQL = 
'
UPDATE PP_Balancing
SET PP_Floor = PP_Floor + 1
WHERE
Sales_Locality IN
    (
        SELECT TOP '+CAST(@CC_N AS VARCHAR(255))+' 
            Sales_Locality
        FROM PP_Balancing
        WHERE Carline = ''01''
        ORDER BY PP_Decimal DESC
    )
AND Carline = ''01''
'

EXEC (@SQL)
```

Comment: SqlDbx is not the actual database engine from what I'm reading. What is the actual database you are using?

Comment: @UnhandledExcepSean It seems MS Sql.

Comment: @jondough Run Select @@version and let us know the results please

Comment: @Nikolaus It looks like SQL Server to me, but there are other databases that look very similar and I don't know easily how to differentiate them. His past questions cover several different databases

Comment: I use the Sqldbx platform for querying. I think it uses Sybase.

Comment: @jondough If you have (maybe) a different database, than Sql Server, why you show me the docs of it? In an different DBMS there could be quite different rules for the syntax.

Comment: @jondough Can you add the hole error to the question?

Comment: If you replace `EXEC(@SQL)` with `PRINT(@SQL)` do you get your expected query? Can you then run that query via copy and paste to see if it is valid?

Comment: please post the entire error returned by Sybase ASE; and if your client/app is masking the error then run your sql code via the `isql` command line tool and post the complete output/error message

Comment: I deleted my answer, because I realized markp‘s answer could go to the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

OP mentioned in comments that this is a Sybase ASE 12.5.4 instance, so we'll look at some ASE specific details ...

OP hasn't (yet) provided the actual error message but I'm guessing it looks something like:

```
select * from
(select top 4 id
     from    sysobjects
     order by name
) dt
go

Msg 154, Level 15, State 53:
Server 'ASE200', Line 2:
An ORDER BY clause is not allowed in a derived table.

select * from
(select id
     from    sysobjects
     order by name
) dt
go

Msg 154, Level 15, State 53:
Server 'ASE200', Line 3:
An ORDER BY clause is not allowed in a derived table.
```

And this is the expected behavior (per the [Sybase ASE manuals](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/topic/com.sybase.infocenter.dc36272.1550/html/commands/X14000.htm)), ie, `order by` is not allowed in a sub-query or derived table.

And while the `top` clause **is** allowed in a sub-query (or derived table), the results will likely not come out as expected (nor be guaranteed to generate the same results on repeated runs) without an `order by` clause.

So that leaves use with the more important question of how to `update` just the 'top X' number of rows.

Now, Sybase ASE does allow the `top` clause in an `update` statement but the lack of support for an `order by` clause (in the `update` statement) makes the `top` pretty much useless if, as in this case, a desired ordering must be applied.

Since the OP is using a variable (@CC_N) to determine the number of rows to update, I'm going to assume we can use another variable to determine the range of `PP_Decimal` values we want to update.

Before I get to the actual `update` statement we need to look at a couple intermediate steps ...

```
-- use variable (@name) to capture the Nth name from sysobjects (order by name)

select top 5 name from sysobjects order by name
go

 name
 ------------------------------
 sysalternates
 sysattributes
 syscolumns
 syscomments
 sysconstraints         <<<=== we want to capture this value in @name

(5 rows affected)

declare @name varchar(255)

-- @name will be assigned each value as it's returned by the query, with
-- the last value (sysconstraints) being the last value assigned to @name

select top 5 @name = name from sysobjects order by name

print @name
go

(5 rows affected)
sysconstraints          <<<=== the contents of @name
```

In this example I plugged in a static `5`, but in the OPs query we need to plug in a variable (`@CC_N`), which is going to require that we dynamically build and execute a query.  But in our case it gets a bit more interesting in that for our dynamic query we also need to capture the results of the query into `@name` so we can use it later on. Lucky for us, ASE allows us to do just this by including our `@name` in the dynamically created query, eg:

```
declare @name   varchar(30),
        @SQL    varchar(100),
        @CC_N   int

select  @CC_N = 5

select @SQL = 'select top ' + convert(varchar(30),@CC_N) + ' @name = name from sysobjects order by name'

select @SQL as 'my query'

exec(@SQL)

select @name as '@name'
go

 @SQL
 -------------------------------------------------------
 select top 5 @name = name from sysobjects order by name

 @name
 ------------------------------
 sysconstraints          <<<=== the contents of @name
```

At this point we should have everything we need to implement the desired `update`.

NOTE: For the sake of this answer I'm going to assume the `PP_Decimal` column is an integer.

```
DECLARE @SQL        varchar(1000),
        @CC_N       int,
        @PP_Decimal int

-- OPs original code to find the Nth value;
-- removed the superfluous 'group by' from the derived table

SELECT  @CC_N = B.PP - A.CC_PP 
FROM
(SELECT SUM(PP_Floor) AS CC_PP
 FROM   PP_Balancing
 WHERE Carline = '01'
) AS A
JOIN PP_National AS B ON A.Carline = B.Carline

-- ??? should OP check for @CC_N >= 1 ???

-- find the Nth PP_Decimal value where 'N' == @CC_N

select @SQL =
"select top " + convert(varchar(30), @CC_N) + " @PP_Decimal = PP_Decimal
 from   PP_Balancing
 where  Carline = '01'
 order by PP_Decimal desc"

-- comment-out/remove the following 'select';
-- only placed here for debugging purposes

select @SQL as '@SQL'

exec(@SQL)

-- at this point @PP_Decimal should contain the last/Nth PP_Decimal value when ordered by PP_Decimal desc;
-- again, following 'select' is for debugging purposes

select @PP_Decimal as '@PP_Decimal'

-- now update our table where PP_Decimal >= @PP_Decimal

update PP_Balancing
set    PP_Floor    = PP_Floor + 1
where  PP_Decimal >= @PP_Decimal
and    Carline     = '01'
go

 @SQL                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
 ---------------------------------------
 select top 5 @PP_Decimal = PP_Decimal     <<<=== for sake of example I plugged in @CC_N=5
 from   PP_Balancing
 where  Carline = '01'
 order by PP_Decimal desc

 @PP_Decimal
 -----------
         538          <<<=== made up number for the sake of this example (since I don't have any actual data)

 (N rows affected)    <<<=== assuming update statement finds @CC_N rows to update
```

NOTE: This solution assumes that `PP_Decimal` values are unique, otherwise the final `update` could update more than `@CC_N` values, eg,

- assume `max(PP_Decimal) = 47`
- assume there are 100 rows with `PP_Decimal = 47`
- assume `@CC_N = 5`
- `@PP_Decimal` would be set to `47` and
- instead of affecting just @CC_N=5 rows, the `update` would update all 100 rows where `PP_Decimal >= 47`

Some variations the user could attempt would be to limit the number of rows to be updated, eg:

```
update top 5 ...
```

or

```
set rowcount 5
update ...
set rowcount 0
```

But these won't guarantee the same rows would be updated on repeated runs.

One other (obvious) solution would be to pull the `top @CC_N` primary key (PK) column values into a #temp table and then have the `update` join with this #temp table to perform the desired `@CC_N` updates.  I'll wait to see if a #temp table solution is acceptable to the OP and/or let someone else post an answer w/ the details of a #temp table based solution.